# Screen flickering after update to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: graphics, 20.04, flicker

After I have updated Ubuntu to 20.04, it started to behave strange. All of a sudden would get stuck, lose bottom navbar, show the purple screeen and at the end go back to normal.Any ideas?

Refer [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbqSHh6uy-I) for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hello  Radisav Savkovic.
People who updated from 16.04LTS to 18.04LTS faced the same issue.

You can change the framerate in the monitor configuration file.

Open terminal,and write the code

```
gedit~/.config/monitors.xml
```

This will open up your monitor configuration file.You've to change the rate, better keep it below 60.Mine was 60.169086456298828.
change the framerates under

```
<rate>flicker rate of your screen</rate>
```

UPDATE[01/06/2020: 3:24 GMT]
Hi,
Please open the terminal(cntrl + alt + T), and copy the code below one by one and paste it in the terminal:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga 
env | grep DESK
```

Post back the results here, it will tell the graphic card make of your device,then we can move forward.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: I'm still having the same problem

Comment: Well, if that doesn't work, then there might be some problem  with the graphic card(don't worry, not the hardware but may be there is some problem with the graphic driver). So i am assuming you' re using a dedicated graphic card.                         You may check out these video on YT           https://youtu.be/HUrM7_5fzXs

Comment: I do think also there is also a problem with graphic card driver, but with which driver. That is problem how to find it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I think it was because of the discrete Graphics Card. I opened the NVIDIA X Server Settings App, chose the `PRIME Profiles` tab, selected `NVIDIA On Demand`, and it worked perfectly after rebooting. It was previously on `NVIDIA (Performance Mode)` and that might have been causing the issue.

Make sure you have the correct drivers in by going to the `Software & Updates` app and checking the `Additional Drivers` tab too.